# Java - IntelliJ Community Maven Web App

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying out Java coming over from .NET and want to make a simple page that does the following:

- Implements RESTful API
- Connects to a MySQL Database
- Implements Role-based Security

I tried out Eclipse but wasn't met with much success, plus the code completion was very slow compared to VS2017. So I'm trying out IntelliJ Community. I've built a Maven project, but my URL is not running, also it looks like I'm not getting any code completion in my .java files. It did not build the app directories automatically.

My POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.johnnytest.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jerseyexample</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jerseyexample Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Snapshot Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>jerseyexample</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <configuration>
              <url>http://localhost:8080/</url>
              <!--<username>joe</username>-->
              <!--<password>joe</password>-->
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.johnnytest.app</param-value>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Java file:

```
package com.johnnytest.app;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/test")
public class MainApp {
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMessage(@PathParam("param") String message) {
        String output = "Jersey says " + message;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

Also it's running Tomcat 7, and I've installed 9 on my system. Is there any way to get it to run on my existing Tomcat install? When I go to any URL on localhost:8080 I just get a blank page in Safari. Running on OSX Sierra.

Comment: This is way too many questions in a single question. You need to keep things focused.  If you have intellij issues you are probably not properly importing the project into intellij and should reference their docs at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven.html

Comment: There's only one question there, how do I get it working on my existing Tomcat 9 install? I'm just giving you the details and telling you what I want to do. ASP.NET Core lets me do all of that out of the box in a few clicks in VS, albeit it runs MSSQL LocalDb by default instead of MySQL. I'm looking for the same in Java with comparable MVC separation of concerns. Is that feasible or should I not be looking to Java to make webapps?

Answer (score 0):

## Launch at Command line

1. if you didn't do it already, download Apache Maven 3.5.0 and add the `/bin` directory to the system `PATH` variable.
2. Enter the directory where the `pom.xml` file is and run the following:

   ```
   mvn clean package
   mvn tomcat7:deploy
   mvn tomcat7:start
   ```

The first command will build the code and produce a Java WAR archive in the subdirectory `target/`.

The second command will deploy the WAR archive to Tomcat application server.

The third command will start Tomcat and expose the server as per configuration (`localhost:8080`).

Don't worry about the command `tomcat7`, even if you're using Tomcat 9 it should be fine.

## Launch within IntellJ

Maven management in IntelliJ is not really optimal, but on the right side you should see a **Maven Projects** pane (if you don't, select "Tools -> View tool buttons" menu). Click and expand.

Under `Lifecycle` you will find the standard Maven goals, so double clicking on `clean` and then `package` will produce the WAR file in a similar manner as explained in the previous section.

Under `Plugins` you will find the Maven goals ruled by the Tomcat plugin. Expand and double click `tomcat7:deploy` and `tomcat7:start`.

## A quick parallel with ASP.NET

If you come from .NET, just think of Tomcat as the Java version of IISExpress that comes bundled with VisualStudio. It is a application server where you deploy the application code and which emulates a webserver service for development.

There are many parallels and also many discrepancies. In general, an application lifecycle in .NET is much more contained, you rarely need anything else beyond VisualStudio and MSBuild, I think. In Java, many things have been created and evolved through the decades thanks to the community: we have different build systems (Maven, Ant, Gradle), the best tooling is command line and there are multiple ways to achieve the same goal.

For example, you are using the Jersey REST library with an underlying app server below (Tomcat), but you could also deploy to a NIO server (Grizzly). If you use extended frameworks like Spring, you generally don't even worry about these things because switching from one way to the other is just a matter of importing a module in your pom.xml instead of another.

Hope this helped you and gave you some directions.

Comment: When I tried to run tomcat7:deploy I got:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/Users/johnernest/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar) to field java.util.Properties.defaults
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future rele

Comment: So it looks like some dependency got messed up. I just installed IntelliJ over the weekend btw.

Comment: I do have a tomcat7:run option and it says it's running, but when I go to the browser I just get a blank page.

Comment: p.s. just checking if we are on the same page, are you trying this address? `localhost:8080/test/foo`

Comment: you can also check the Tomcat logs (it is a subdirectory of the Tomcat main directory) and open the most recent. See if there is some descriptive error.

Comment: Finally, I googled your error. Is there any chance that yuo're running Java 9 ? I would suggest to go back to Java 8, at least for now, many libraries (including XStream, apparently) are not Java 9 ready yet.

Comment: Yes I'm on Java 9, that might have been the issue.